# X11 window does not get refreshed until it gets an event

Tags: c++, graphics, x11, cairo

In my application (`cairo` and `X11`), the user can issue a command whereby the drawing is enlarged. To be able to grab the entire drawing as a pattern, I enlarge the drawing surface to match the current scale (the drawing is just a graph, so this can be afforded as far as memory is concerned). Beginning with a certain scale though, the X11 window refuses to refresh until it gets an event (e.g. loss of focus, which is not even handled in my application).

I tried refreshing the window using both `XFlush()` and `XSync()`.

Does this look like a bug in the windowing system? If not, what should I do? Everything works perfectly with smaller scales.

**EDIT 1**: After much work with `gdb`, I found that the problem is not with the window not refreshing. Rather, at a certain point a call to `XNextEvent()` causes the window to become all black.

**EDIT2**: It looks like calls to `XNextEvent()` actually cause the window to be refreshed! And here is the code that caused the problem:

```
struct PatternLock {
    PatternLock(Graphics &g)
        : g_(g) {
        p_ = cairo_get_source(g_.cr);
        cairo_pattern_reference(p_);
    }

    ~PatternLock() {
        // The commented lines caused the problem. How come?
        // cairo_set_source_rgb(g_.cr, 0, 0, 0);
        // cairo_paint(g_.cr);
        cairo_set_source(g_.cr, p_);
        cairo_paint(g_.cr);
        cairo_pattern_destroy(p_);
    }

private:
    Graphics &g_;
    cairo_pattern_t *p_;
};
```

Suppose the we have this code for moving the drawing:

```
{
    PatternLock lock{g};
    ... // Change of transformation matrix
}
```

It somehow happen that the effect of the commented lines in the destructor of `PatternLock` becomes visible (hence the black screen), but the effect of the following lines does not. I realize that the commented code is actually unneeded. But still, how does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

If my memory serves me correct, there's a limit to Drawables (e.g. Windows and Pixmaps) of 4096x4096 pixels. You should check the return values of your calls to XCreatePixmap() etc.

Either way, just enlarging the pixmap to draw your drawing is Bad Design (tm), and will inevitably lead to a very slow program. Learn how to deal with zoom and pan (tip: work from the center of your viewport, not the corners). Assuming your drawing is vector-based (i.e. lines and curves) you can optimize painting a lot at high zoom factors.

If you must grab a complete graph at a resolutions larger than 4096 pixels you must implement tiling, which isn't that hard if you have zoom and pan already.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. However, the limit does not seem to explain it, since things continue to work perfectly as soon as the window receives an event (e.g. loss of focus).

Comment: Hmm, odd. Are you sure it's not after a fixed number of resize events? Maybe you're running out of resources; this kind of behaviour is typical of that. BTW, XSync() and XFlush() do not force a refresh of the contents of your window (nothing does...)

Comment: No. In fact, this behavior is sporadic. I can even scale further after that. This causes things to become slow, but the updates happen! What do you mean by saying that nothing forces a refresh of contents of the window? Applications do need a guarantee that the contents are refreshed!

Comment: Okay, let me rephrase that. There's no way in X to say "refresh this portion of the window"; in stead you just paint the section you want, when you want. Then there are Expose events, which are generated externally because of moving windows, etc. Either way, XSync/XFlush flush the buffer but do not refresh the window, as you wrote in your OP. Perhaps it is time to post some code?

Comment: "you just paint the section you want, when you want". But what causes the things that I painted to become visible? As for posting code, I will think about making a self-contained example.

Comment: 'But what causes the things that I painted to become visible?' If you draw on a Window (with XCopyArea or any of the primitives like XDrawRectangle, XDrawLine, etc) **that** is shown on your screen.

Comment: I got some understanding and posted the code that caused the problem. I still do not understand how it caused the problem...